# Use variables inside YAD

Tags: bash, variables, yad

I can't find a way to using variables inside YAD

I have the following script:

```
 #!/bin/bash   
USERS=$(awk '{print $1}' `pwd`/names.txt | sed -e ':a' -e 'N' -e '$!ba' -e 's/\n/!/g')

YAD=$(yad --title="Hello" \
--form \
--field="User:":CB \
'$USERS!New User')
```

My working file (`names.txt`) contains the following:

```
Ramiro  1234
Dalia   5678
Persona 9012
```

But that script results in a list with only two options: "$USERS" and "New User", not the contents of `names.txt`

Note that the correct syntax for a list in YAD is as follows:

```
YAD=$(yad --title="Hello" \
--form \
--field="User:":CB \
'Ramiro!Dalia!Persona!New User')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not allowing the variable expansion (`$USERS`) because of the single quotes. Use double quotes.

Replace this:

```
'$USERS!New User'
```

With this:

```
"$USERS!New User"
```

Comment: Well that was very fast and effective! Perfect answer! Ty.